# How to use mustache notation within <script> in a nodered ui template

Tags: javascript, templates, node-red

My node-red UI template node starts with a script like this:

```
<script>
    (function($scope) {
```

later on in the script there is an if statement like this:

```
} else if ($scope.msg.topic === "temperature_avg") {
        
        high = 88;
        mid = 65;
        low = 60;
        size= "0.9em";
        }
```

Instead of having the variables hardcoded inside this script I want to pass them via msg.payload.ranges1 and have the if statement looking like this:

```
} else if ($scope.msg.topic === "temperature_avg") {
        
        {{msg.payload.ranges1}}
        }
```

But its not working.

Comment: Please clarify "not working". What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: I wanted {{msg.payload.ranges1}} to turn into `high = 88;
        mid = 65;
        low = 60;
        size= "0.9em";` but it didnt, I am not sure what happened.

Comment: So what did it turn into? Also, what do your data look like, anyway?

Answer (score -1):

I turned ui template into a subflow, and copied it for each flow, being able to edit all of them from the single subflow place.